# How do you find the previous month in YYYY/MM Format

Tags: python, datetime

It's quite simple. I like to find the previous month for the current time, but in YYYY/MM Date Format. Ideally using Datetime.

Comment: Any attempt from yourself?

Comment: Current_Date = dt.datetime.now()
Submission_Month = Current_Date.month - 1 if Current_Date.month > 1 else 12
Submission_Year = Current_Date.year if Current_Date.month > Submission_Month else Current_Date.year - 1

Comment: I know this will get me the right year and month but I want this is the correct format with and ' / ' in between, just not sure how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `months` with `relativedelta`:

```py
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> (datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%Y/%m')
'2019/08'
```

This covers the case you said:

```py
>> (datetime.strptime('01/03/2019', '%d/%m/%Y') - relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%Y/%m')
'2019/02'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)).strftime('%Y/%m')
```

This may suffice depending on your needs, a more sophisticated approach may use libraries from pip, like dateutil

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
(datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%Y/%m')
```

Regards

Comment: I had thought about your first approach, but for the 01/03/2019 would mean 31/01/2019

Comment: The second looks great

Comment: Yeah the first approach is very flawed, but it may work if you know the dates that you gonna handle, is okay for little lived scripts where you know the data you're processing. Anything more rigorous would go for the second

Answer (score 0):

Using only the datetime module from the standard library, we can get the month and year from 15 days before the start of our month:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def previous_month():
    format = '%Y/%m'
    d = date.today().replace(day=1) # first day of the month
    return date.strftime(d-timedelta(days=15), format) # 15 days earlier is in the previous month

previous_month()
# '2019/08
```